# What part of speech is 'pooped' in "I am pooped"

Tags: parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis

I have a wager that 'pooped' in "I am pooped" is not an adjective; however the betting party contends that it is an adjective since "it describes the state of the subject, I".

The other party also cites [the wictionary entry for pooped as evidence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pooped).

I have found evidence that pooped is used as a verb, such as [this CMU automated grammar parser](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/link/construct-page-4.cgi); however the grammar parser concedes it is guessing at the part of speech (note the [!]) in the output...

```
++++Time                                          0.00 seconds (59.77 total)
Found 1 linkage (1 with no P.P. violations)
  Unique linkage. cost vector = (UNUSED=0 DIS=0 AND=0 LEN=3)

 +-SX-+---Pv--+
 |    |       |
I.p am.v pooped[!].v 

Constituent tree:

(S (NP I)
   (VP am
       (VP pooped)))
```

Could someone explain the part of speech that 'pooped' is above, as well as the rationale for choosing this response?

Comment: I think your betting partner is on a hiding to nothing. He'd have more chance if you accepted something like *"When we play squash, I'm always the pooped one"* as your test sentence. But we don't normally use *pooped* that way - it's a standard "past participle used adjectivally". Effectively, an inflected form of the **verb** "to poop" *(OED a: intr. To break down, ‘conk’ out. b: trans. To tire, to exhaust)* that we don't actually use as a standard verb very much. Except those who use it for *defecate, crap, shit*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pooped when used as a verb is a synonym for "to defecate". For example: "I pooped in the bathroom." In the sentence you're asking about, though, "pooped" is definitely used as an adjective. This is because the verb "to be" is a copulative verb (more commonly known as a **linking** verb), and copulative verbs by nature link a noun or adjective to the subject. For example, if we modified the above sentence to "I am happy", it is in meaning "I = happy". Now we know that it is either a noun or an adjective, but (to me at least) it is clear that "pooped" isn't a noun, as one can't say "I have a pooped in my backpack".

So your answer is, **it's an adjective**.

Answer (score 2):

As defined by the [Cambridge Dictionary Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/pooped), pooped is an *adjective* meaning

> very tired:
>
> *Students are pooped because they’re juggling classes, studying, and jobs.*

Similarly, the [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pooped) defines it as

> exhausted
>
> *The boys are too pooped to fight.*

It has been in use for some time.  [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary (1913)](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=pooped&use1913=on) defines it as

> Tired; exhausted, fatigued

Comment: Three excellent sources that list it as an adjective.  Well done.  Time for the OP to pay up, I feel.